# I was trying understand the working of SURF and SIFT, but I am getting fatal error when I execute the code

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, fatal-error, javacv

This is my code and the line where I am getting the error is :

```
featureDetector.detect(objectImage, objectKeyPoints);
```

I don't have any knowledge about what the error is all about since, error is not specified in brief.

I am running the code on Ubuntu.

The error I am getting is as follows :

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
>   SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9b24f3d747, pid=29767,
>   tid=0x00007f9b438b2700
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build
>   1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)  Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops) 
>   Problematic frame:  C  [libopencv_features2d.so.2.4+0x59747] 
>   cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector >&, cv::Mat const&) const+0x4d7
>
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable
>   core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as: 
>   /home/chandansr/MajorProjectParts/MajorProjectPart1/MotionDetection/hs_err_pid29767.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.

```
public class SURFDetector {

static{
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String bookObject = "/home/chandansr/source2.png";
    String bookScene = "/home/chandansr/temp3.png";

    System.out.println("Started....");
    System.out.println("Loading images...");
    Mat objectImage = Highgui.imread(bookObject);
    Mat sceneImage = Highgui.imread(bookScene);

    MatOfKeyPoint objectKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
    System.out.println("Detecting key points...");
    featureDetector.detect(objectImage, objectKeyPoints);
    System.out.println("Detected key points...");
    KeyPoint[] keypoints = objectKeyPoints.toArray();
    System.out.println(keypoints);

    MatOfKeyPoint objectDescriptors = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    DescriptorExtractor descriptorExtractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);
    System.out.println("Computing descriptors...");
    descriptorExtractor.compute(objectImage, objectKeyPoints, objectDescriptors);

    // Create the matrix for output image.
    Mat outputImage = new Mat(objectImage.rows(), objectImage.cols(), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Scalar newKeypointColor = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);

    System.out.println("Drawing key points on object image...");
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(objectImage, objectKeyPoints, outputImage, newKeypointColor, 0);

    // Match object image with the scene image
    MatOfKeyPoint sceneKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint sceneDescriptors = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    System.out.println("Detecting key points in background image...");
    featureDetector.detect(sceneImage, sceneKeyPoints);
    System.out.println("Computing descriptors in background image...");
    descriptorExtractor.compute(sceneImage, sceneKeyPoints, sceneDescriptors);

    Mat matchoutput = new Mat(sceneImage.rows() * 2, sceneImage.cols() * 2, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Scalar matchestColor = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);

    List<MatOfDMatch> matches = new LinkedList<MatOfDMatch>();
    DescriptorMatcher descriptorMatcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED);
    System.out.println("Matching object and scene images...");
    descriptorMatcher.knnMatch(objectDescriptors, sceneDescriptors, matches, 2);

    System.out.println("Calculating good match list...");
    LinkedList<DMatch> goodMatchesList = new LinkedList<DMatch>();

    float nndrRatio = 0.7f;

    for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
        MatOfDMatch matofDMatch = matches.get(i);
        DMatch[] dmatcharray = matofDMatch.toArray();
        DMatch m1 = dmatcharray[0];
        DMatch m2 = dmatcharray[1];

        if (m1.distance <= m2.distance * nndrRatio) {
            goodMatchesList.addLast(m1);

        }
    }

    if (goodMatchesList.size() >= 7) {
        System.out.println("Object Found!!!");

        List<KeyPoint> objKeypointlist = objectKeyPoints.toList();
        List<KeyPoint> scnKeypointlist = sceneKeyPoints.toList();

        LinkedList<Point> objectPoints = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Point> scenePoints = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < goodMatchesList.size(); i++) {
            objectPoints.addLast(objKeypointlist.get(goodMatchesList.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
            scenePoints.addLast(scnKeypointlist.get(goodMatchesList.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
        }

        MatOfPoint2f objMatOfPoint2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        objMatOfPoint2f.fromList(objectPoints);
        MatOfPoint2f scnMatOfPoint2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        scnMatOfPoint2f.fromList(scenePoints);

        Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(objMatOfPoint2f, scnMatOfPoint2f, Calib3d.RANSAC, 3);

        Mat obj_corners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
        Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);

        obj_corners.put(0, 0, new double[]{0, 0});
        obj_corners.put(1, 0, new double[]{objectImage.cols(), 0});
        obj_corners.put(2, 0, new double[]{objectImage.cols(), objectImage.rows()});
        obj_corners.put(3, 0, new double[]{0, objectImage.rows()});

        System.out.println("Transforming object corners to scene corners...");
        Core.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, homography);

        Mat img = Highgui.imread(bookScene, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

        Core.line(img, new Point(scene_corners.get(0, 0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(1, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line(img, new Point(scene_corners.get(1, 0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(2, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line(img, new Point(scene_corners.get(2, 0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(3, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line(img, new Point(scene_corners.get(3, 0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(0, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

        System.out.println("Drawing matches image...");
        MatOfDMatch goodMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
        goodMatches.fromList(goodMatchesList);

        Features2d.drawMatches(objectImage, objectKeyPoints, sceneImage, sceneKeyPoints, goodMatches, matchoutput, matchestColor, newKeypointColor, new MatOfByte(), 2);

        Highgui.imwrite("output//outputImage.jpg", outputImage);
        Highgui.imwrite("output//matchoutput.jpg", matchoutput);
        Highgui.imwrite("output//img.jpg", img);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Object Not Found");
    }

    System.out.println("Ended....");
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code on another machine? If not, I would suggest running it on another machine as this looks like more of a hardware problem. You could also try downgrading your JVM to solve this issue.

Comment: Ok, I will try it once. Thanks for your advice.